# Add to Cart on hover - Shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify

trying to have the "add to cart" button as a hover when mouse goes over that product. Currently its like this in boxes underneath each product.

Is it a simple solution or do I require more complex coding for this in Shopify back-end?

[image]

Comment: This is a bad idea or at least incomplete….Hover doesn’t exist on mobile, the button will appears just on computers, so you need a solution when device is tablet or smaller.  After that this is super easy to do with CSS, you can create a div with absolute position and z-index upper that display in hover. This div will contains a hide form doing post to “/cart” with hide inputs of qty, and variant id, plus a visible submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the potential code. "Potential" - because I am able to display floating `add to cart` button when mouse hovers over a product. Issue is when I try to click that floating `add to cart` button, it is not receiving click event even if i have captured its click event via some other javascript.If someone can suggest some improvement to this, we would have working , floating add to cart button. Thanks

```
const productCardWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.product-card-wrapper');

// Loop through each instance and add event listeners
productCardWrappers.forEach((productCardWrapper) => {
    // Get the Add to Cart button element within the current instance
    const addToCartButton = productCardWrapper.querySelector('.variant-button');

    // Add a mouseover event listener to the current instance
    productCardWrapper.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        // Show the Add to Cart button when the mouse is over the current product card
        addToCartButton.style.display = 'block';
    });

    // Add a mouseout event listener to the current instance to hide the button
    productCardWrapper.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        // Hide the Add to Cart button when the mouse leaves the current product card
        addToCartButton.style.display = 'none';
    });
});'''
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
function main(){
document.getElementById('cart').style.color = 'white';
document.getElementById('cart').style.background-color = 'black';
document.getElementById('cart').style.translateY = '-50%';
document.getElementById('item').style.opacity = '24%';
document.getElementById('cart').style.opacity = '100%';
}
```

```html
<div class = "item" onmouseover=main()>
<!--image,etc..
 give cart's id as cart
 give item's id as item
 -->
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This code is wrong in many ways